# How to make mpi4py to use MPI Version 3.0

Tags: mpi, mpi4py

I have recently installed mpi4py version 2.0.0 for python3. I want this API to use MPI version 3.0, but by default it is using MPI version 2.0. How can I make it use MPI version 3.0.

PS: I installed mpi4py using "pip3 install mpi4py".

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/install.html#using-pip-or-easy-install)? Are aware of the differences between MPI and an MPI implementation?

Comment: Hi Zulan, I have read the documentation. By the way I could not find the answer for my question. While installing mpi4py in two different machines, one has MPI.VERSION 2.0 while the other has MPI.VERSION 3.0

Comment: I suspect that `mpicc` / `MPICC` is something different on those machines.

Answer (score 1):

mpi4py is merely a wrapper for you to call MPI functions in Python. Those MPI functions (and the version of the MPI standard implemented) are provided by the MPI implementation (e.g. openmpi or mpich) you installed on your machine, not mpi4py.

So what you need to do:

1. Make sure you have installed a proper MPI implementation which supports/implements MPI standard 3
2. Make sure mpi4py selects that implementation, which is usually been done by changing that MPI implementation to the default one (or you can simply remove all other MPI implementations you installed)
3. Make sure mpi4py works properly with that MPI implementation (usually by rebuilding and reinstalling mpi4py)

I'm not sure about before, but at least openmpi 2.1.1 support MPI 3.